# Python sqlite3 how to dynamically search for null

Tags: python, sqlite

I am try select, modify, or delete rows using sqlite3 which can have a null value in a column. I am also trying to this dynamically so I can search for null value by using the Python literal `None`.

This works just fine:

```py
name = "John"
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM users WHERE name = ?", (name,))
```

However, this does not work:

```py
name = None
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM users WHERE name = ?", (name,))
```

I understand that SQL is strange and I have to do `is null`, but is there an elegant (and safe) way of doing this in one line?

Answer (score 1):

While you could conjure up a one-liner to construct the right query, it's simpler to branch based on the value.

```py
if name is None:
    stmt = 'DELETE FROM users WHERE name IS NULL'
    cursor.execute(stmt)
else:
    stmt = 'DELETE FROM users WHERE name = ?'
    cursor.execute(stmt, (name,))
```

If you need something more dynamic - for example multiple columns in the WHERE clause, any one of which might be NULL - I would recommend using a query-building tool or an ORM rather than trying to handle all the permutations yourself.

Answer (score 0):

While I'd go with safety and run your `DELETE FROM` as two separate statements, with the second explicitly using `DELETE FROM users WHERE name = null`, it is possible to do what you want:

```
if inputname = None:
    name = "null"
else:
    name = inputname

cursor.execute("DELETE FROM users WHERE name = '%s'", name)
```

If you're after a C-like ternary operator, you need at least Python 3.10 iirc - but I'd avoid that in favour of making your operations very clear for whoever has to maintain this code after you.

Comment: I was thinking of "safe" in terms of "make explicit what you are deleting, when you delete it". As to whether f-strings won't quote correctly - references please?

Comment: Any reputable Python/SQL docs will warn against using string formatting for query values  e.g. (https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3, https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters).

Comment: For example, consider a user named O'Brien

Comment: Thankyou for reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

From [SQL Language Expressions/Operators, and Parse-Affecting Attributes](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#operators_and_parse_affecting_attributes):

> The IS and IS NOT operators work like = and != except when one or both
> of the operands are NULL. In this case, if both operands are NULL,
> then the IS operator evaluates to 1 (true) and the IS NOT operator
> evaluates to 0 (false). If one operand is NULL and the other is not,
> then the IS operator evaluates to 0 (false) and the IS NOT operator is
> 1 (true). It is not possible for an IS or IS NOT expression to
> evaluate to NULL.

This means that you can have 1 query that uses the operator `IS` and it will work if you pass `None` (which will be translated to `null` inside the query) or any other valid string:

```
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM users WHERE name IS ?", (name,))
```